# usage of Date.parse

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to display a graph with  HighCharts en i got stacked with generating series to display. What i have is series of timestamps in database. I want to display difference between events so on Xaxis i get time between events (current t2 - previous t2) en on Y I get time. So now i wanted to use Date.parse to get seconds but its returning nothing. Am I using wrong Date.parse function? because when i put int number it displays a flat line.

```
    $i = 0;     
    foreach ($metingen as $index => $m) { 
        if($i != 0) $js .= ',';
        $js .= "{name: '";
        $js .= "Event time " . substr($m[0]['t1'],0,16);
        $js .= "', data: [";
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($m as $ms) {
            if($j != 0) $js .= ',';
            $js .= Date.parse("2012-01-30 18:21:49")-
                            Date.parse("2012-01-30 18:21:47";//$ms['antaal'];
            $j++;
        }
        $js .=  "]}";
        $i++;
    }
```

database query returns time in this format:

```
t1                  antaal  t2
2012-01-30 18:21:41 | 0 |   2012-01-30 18:21:42
2012-01-30 18:21:41 | 1 |   2012-01-30 18:21:43
2012-01-30 18:21:41 | 2 |   2012-01-30 18:21:53
2012-01-30 18:21:41 | 3 |   2012-01-30 18:21:59
```

Comment: That is why you should not mix Javascript and PHP. What is this mess? Please explain what you're trying to do in this "code".

Comment: this mess returns what I need, it generates series for graph HighCharts  but the Date.parse returns nothing. Actually I am new in Javascript so dont even know how to debug (I get nothing on page when using Date.parse())

Comment: No problem if it works for you. But when you're posting it to others, you should try to clean it up a bit. Is this in your PHP or Javascript code? What is that `series: [` at the top?

Comment: my excuses! its snippet form [HighCarts](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/edge/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/)

Comment: I guess it is also some Javascript echoed with PHP (yikes). The opening `"` is missing from your snippet so the code colorer breaks. Could you do something about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a T

`var date = new Date(Date.parse("2012-01-30 18:21:49".replace(" ","T")))`

and for Safari add a Z:

`var date = new Date(Date.parse("2012-01-30 18:21:49".replace(" ","T")+"Z"))`

or have

```
t1                  antaal  t2
2012-01-30T18:21:41Z | 0 |   2012-01-30T18:21:42Z
2012-01-30T18:21:41Z | 1 |   2012-01-30T18:21:43Z
2012-01-30T18:21:41Z | 2 |   2012-01-30T18:21:53Z
2012-01-30T18:21:41Z | 3 |   2012-01-30T18:21:59Z
```

However for Safari you need a little more

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/QkasD/

Also I think you mean

```
   $js .= 'Date.parse("'.$m1.'")-Date.parse("'.$m2.'");';
```

or similar

Comment: Your PHP is not valid. Show the complete script

Comment: Just looked it up in the ECMA spec. The standard is "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ" where Z is either Z for zulu or quote "either + or - followed by a time expression HH:mm" this way it works in Safari too.

Comment: its worked for me! Thanks mplungjan! I messed up with " and ' thats why i didnot get any thing on page